# TensorFlow 2.0 Tutorial Issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am following the official tutorial at https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/sequences/text_classification_rnn, and I encountered a problem. The following line causes the error:

```
train_dataset = train_dataset.padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, train_dataset.output_shapes)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "main.py", line 30, in 
>       train_dataset = train_dataset.padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, train_dataset.output_shapes)
>   AttributeError: 'ShuffleDataset' object has no attribute 'output_shapes

What am I missing?
Here is my half-completed code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow.keras

def plot_graphs(history, string):
    plt.plot(history.history[string])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_'+string])
    plt.xlabel("Epochs")
    plt.ylabel(string)
    plt.legend([string, 'val_'+string])
    plt.show()
dataset, info = tfds.load('imdb_reviews/subwords8k', with_info=True,
                          as_supervised=True)
train_dataset, test_dataset = dataset['train'], dataset['test']
tokenizer = info.features['text'].encoder
print ('Vocabulary size: {}'.format(tokenizer.vocab_size))
# sample_string = 'TensorFlow is cool.'
# tokenized_string = tokenizer.encode(sample_string)
# print ('Tokenized string is {}'.format(tokenized_string))
# original_string = tokenizer.decode(tokenized_string)
# print ('The original string: {}'.format(original_string))
# assert original_string == sample_string
# for ts in tokenized_string:
#     print ('{} ----> {}'.format(ts, tokenizer.decode([ts])))
BUFFER_SIZE = 10000
BATCH_SIZE = 64
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE)
train_dataset = train_dataset.padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, train_dataset.output_shapes)
test_dataset = test_dataset.padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, test_dataset.output_shapes)
```

Comment: Have a look at  https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/issues/102

Comment: I tried your code on TF 2 and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace

```
train_dataset = train_dataset.padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, train_dataset.output_shapes)
```

with

```
train_dataset = train_dataset.padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, tf.compat.v1.data.get_output_shapes(train_dataset))
```

and also replace

```
test_dataset = test_dataset.padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, test_dataset.output_shapes)
```

with

```
test_dataset = test_dataset.padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, tf.compat.v1.data.get_output_shapes(test_dataset))
```

Comment: Please add some supplementary notes explaining your solution.